# How to enable and test emailmodule of OpenSimulator?

Tags: opensimulator

I want to try and test `emailmodule` of [OpenSimulator](http://opensimulator.org/) for sending emails. I have setup test grid in `Standalone` mode.

I have enabled relavant settigns in `OpenSim.ini`

```ini
[Startup]
    emailmodule = DefaultEmailModule

[SMTP]
    enabled = true
    enableEmailToExternalObjects = true
    enableEmailToSMTP = true
    SMTP_SERVER_FROM = "alok@somedomain.com"
    SMTP_SERVER_TLS = true
    SMTP_SERVER_HOSTNAME = "email-smtp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"
    SMTP_SERVER_PORT = 587
    SMTP_SERVER_LOGIN = "user"
    SMTP_SERVER_PASSWORD = "password"
    SMTP_VerifyCertChain = true
    SMTP_VerifyCertNames = true
```

In the `OpenSim.exe` console log I am seeing

```
09:18:06 - [EMAIL]: Activated DefaultEmailModule
```

How can I test `emailmodule` if its working or now?

Answer (score 0):

For me to understand what test you want to perform, I need to understand the objective you want to achieve.

If it's via the LSL llEmail() function's communication mechanism, I can create a script to see if I can send an email via script.

I'll see if a basic LSL script works in opensim and test it

Below is a basic script.

```
string mail = "YOUREMAIL@YOURDOMAIN";
string header = "Someone touched your letterbox!";
default
{
touch_start(integer num_detected)
 {
    integer i = 0;
    key id = llDetectedKey(0);
    string name = llDetectedName(0);
    llEmail(mail, header, "I was touched by: '" + name + "' (" + (string)id + ").");
    llSay(0, "Email sent to TEST@######.com");
 }
}
```

It's something simple, it detects that someone has clicked on the object and sends a message by email, if it's working it will deliver something to the string's email box